# Generate only certain combinations from a list in Python

Tags: python, list, combinations, python-itertools

I have used the following script to generate all combinations:

```
import itertools
x = 7
my_list = range(1, 11)
for k in [x]:
   for sublist in itertools.combinations(my_list, k):
      print sublist
```

For the second part I will take 6 random elements from range(1, 11). Let's call them my_second_list.
I need to generate the minimum number of combinations of my_list in order to obtain at least one combination to include let's say 5 elements from my_second_list.

Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: Can you just filter the output by examining `sublist`?

Comment: I think you need to edit your question and include your expected output.

Comment: I have edited the question to be more explicit. The previous version had no sense. I must have been very tired when last night when I wrote it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools

x = 7
my_list = range(1,11)

for k in [x]: # isn't this just 7?
    your_output = (combination for combination in itertools.combinations(my_list,k) if all(element in combination for element in [1,2,3,4,5]))
```

It's ugly as heck, but that's how I'd do it (if I'm understanding your question correctly. You're trying to get only those combinations that contain a certain subset of items, right? If you want all combinations BEFORE and INCLUDING that first combination that contains the subset of items, I'd do:

```
accumulator = list()
subset = [1,2,3,4,5] # or whatever
for k in [x]:
    for combination in itertools.combinations(my_list,k):
        accumulator.append(combination)
        if all(el in combination for el in subset):
            break
```

Depending on your exact use case you may want to consider defining `subset` as a `set` (e.g. `{1,2,3,4,5}`) and do `subset.issubset(set(combination))` but it's hard to tell if that's better or not without doing some profiling.

Comment: @wiseguy0106 it's still not very clear. Do you just need the first combination such that some `N` elements are shared with another list `L`? How many elements is `L`? Can `N` change?

Comment: to be more clear: i have 2 lists: A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] and B = 6 random elements from list A. I need to generate the minimum combinations of list A taken 7 in order to obtain at least one combination to include 5 elements from list B. It's similar to a reduced lotto system: you play 10 numbers in certain combinations and if you get right let's say 5 of the winning ones you are guaranteed to have at least 1 combination which contains 4 of the winning numbers. And you do not need to play all the possible combinations.